# PHP and (isset($_POST[''])) issue

Tags: php

Apologies if this question is duplicated, I have however not found an obvious answer to my question. I am a complete novice with [php](/questions/tagged/php), be kind! When I load the following code, it appears to run `if(isset($_POST['test']))` even though I have not pressed the button `"test"`. I only want the code to execute when I press the "`test`" button. How do I resolve this?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
        $value=$content->book->price;
        $sum=$content->book->price;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['test'])) {
        $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
        $value=$content->book->price;
        $content->book->price = $value + 1.0;
        $content->asXML("books.xml");
        $sum=$content->book->price;
    }
?>

<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="checkbox" id="i1check1" onchange="toggleDisabled(this.checked)"> Alarm 01
        <input type="text" id="i1text1" name="i1" size="80" maxlength="128" value="<?php echo @$sum;?>"/>
        <input type="submit" id="i1btn1" name="update" value="Update"/>
        <input type="submit" id="i1btn2" name="test" value="Test"/>
    </form>

    <script>
        function toggleDisabled(_checked) {
            document.getElementById('i1text1').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
            document.getElementById('i1btn1').disabled = _checked ? false : true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: its because you have set the value field of text inputs

Comment: your code inside "if(isset($_POST['update'])){" and "if(isset($_POST['test'])){" will not run till you dn't press "update" or "test" button,you have to define $_POST['update'] is set or not as a variable so you have to use (isset)

Comment: Is your answer correct anyway!! Have you tested it?

Comment: >> When I load the following code, it appears to run if(isset($_POST['test'])) even though I have not pressed the button "test". Load means what? I have checked it and is working fine. if you refresh the page after clicking any of the buttons, then it will get into the same respective condition as the submitted value is available in the $_POST

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please Try This**

```
if(isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] == "Update"){
    $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
    $value=$content->book->price;
    $sum=$content->book->price;
}

if(isset($_POST['test']) && $_POST['test'] == "Test"){
    $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
    $value=$content->book->price;
    $content->book->price = $value + 1.0;
    $content->asXML("books.xml");
    $sum=$content->book->price;
}
```

Comment: his code works fine, no mean of 
if(isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] == "Update"){

Comment: @Manish Jesani Your suggestion solved my issue with value being updated upon form load. However this has created another issue that the value is not displayed upon form load (only after button click). How do I resolve this, or is there a better way than my current method?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you should use [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Whenever form is submitted, all form's **name** attributes will be received in **$_POST** array. It doesn't matter either it is set or not.

You can do filtration using **!empty** because it will check **set + has value**. While isset check only **set**.

```
if(!empty($_POST['update'])){ // !empty instead of isset

    $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
    $value=$content->book->price;
    $sum=$content->book->price;

}
if(!empty($_POST['test'])){  // !empty instead of isset

    $content=simplexml_load_file("books.xml");
    $value=$content->book->price;
    $content->book->price = $value + 1.0;
    $content->asXML("books.xml");
    $sum=$content->book->price;
}
```

**Suggestion**:- You have written `echo @$sum;` in form. Never hide your errors using **@**. Instead of doing this, you should ON [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) in development mode.

You should write that statement as below.

```
 echo empty($sum) ? '' : $sum;  // ternary operator
```

Comment: your suggestion to rather use "!empty" still resulted in $sum adding +1 every time the form was reloaded. As I mentioned in my original post I am new to PHP so I would really appreciate clarity on your suggestion to not hide my errors. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @ is used to hide errors.  Just remove it and ON your error reporting. It will show you notice.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Ravi Hirani